# How can i program with C++ in NAO v6?

Tags: c++, nao-robot

I'm looking in the internet how to **program with c++ in NAO v6**, but i can't found nothing, i know how to program with python in the choregraphe but i cant find the way to program with c++. There's some tutorial or something like that, or if it is simple, can you help me, please?

[image: printscreen]

Comment: This is probably too involved and therefore too broad for this site. However I googled your question title and this came up: http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/cpp/install_guide.html#cpp-install-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are tutorials in the documentation of NAOqi 2.8 (which is the software used on NAO v6). See here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/cpp/index.html - it includes both tutorials and API reference.